# A potentially dangerous Request.Path with strange URL

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I was viewing my elmah.axd file (which can only be viewed by one user). I have seen the following error (more than 100 ). with strange url

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?).
```

URL

```
/elmah.axd/detail?id=DC68F66B-51F0-40AB-BF4D-D3265B746393&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=ldg9U9blGs6T0gG87IC4AQ&amp;ved=0CIsBEBYwFA&amp;usg=AFQjCNEs9W_NO8XeJOP6f0MsyFnvl2QFYg/administrator/components/com_acymailing/inc/openflash/php-ofc-library/ofc_upload_image.php
```

I know what it is meant for Potentially dangerous error. my main concern is this url what is it is this any sort of attack ??

Comment: See http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/37314

Comment: My site is of .net so i shouldn't be concerned about this issue Am I right??

Comment: Well you should be somewhat concerned that someone is attacking your site, but I guess these days that's to be expected. This particular attack won't be doing you any harm.

Comment: Probably some script kiddie running some uber-hacker's scripts to see if they could get a loophole for a feasible intrusion. Just block those IP's or something.